# Reactjs onClick not rerendering data when sent to child component to get info from api

Tags: reactjs, components

I am new to react, trying to call api to render data on specific user onClick, data changes on different clicks but only after the user presses a clear button, tried everything i can think of, componentWillUpdate, forceUpdate, but nothing works, i have link to codepen below, any advice is appreciated

https://codepen.io/dau328/pen/ZaVwaQ?editors=0110

```
    class Person extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.props.test = "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/";
    this.state = {
      "characters": [
        {
          "name": "Luke Skywalker",
          "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
        },
        {
          "name": "Darth Vader",
          "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/4/"
        },
        {
          "name": "Obi-wan Kenobi",
          "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "R2-D2",
          "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/"
        }
      ],

      url: "",
      person: ""

    };


  }

    handleClick(cName, person, e) {
   // console.log(person);

        this.setState({person: person});
        this.setState({url: cName});
        this.props.test = cName;
     // console.log(this.props.test);
     // console.log(`cName ${cName}`);

  }




   _renderSubComp(link) {
    var url = <FilmDemo subreddit={this.state.url} />;
   if(link === 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/'){
     return url;
   }

   if(link === 'https://swapi.co/api/people/4/'){
     return url;
   }

     if(link === 'https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/'){
     return url;
   }

     if(link === 'https://swapi.co/api/people/3/'){
     return url;
   }

   }

    render(){
      var people = this.state.characters.map(function(p) {
      return  <p>{p.name}</p> ;

    });

      return (
        <div>
         <p className="clearButton" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'null', '' )}><button>Clear</button></p>
        <div className="people">
          <p className="peopleName" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.characters[0].url, people[0] )}>{people[0]} </p>
           <p className="peopleName" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.characters[1].url, people[1] )}>{people[1]} </p>
           <p className="peopleName" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.characters[2].url, people[2] )}>{people[2]}</p>
           <p className="peopleName" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.characters[3].url, people[3] )}>{people[3]}</p>
          </div>




          <span className="info-films example"><h3>{this.state.person}</h3>

            {this._renderSubComp(this.state.url)} </span>

          </div>
        );
    }

}

class Films extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);

     this.state = {
      films: [],
       director: [],
       date: []

    };

 }



   componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`${this.props.name}`)
      .then(res => {
        var filmTitle = res.data.title;
        var director = res.data.director;
        var date = new Date(res.data.release_date);
        var dateFormat = date.toDateString();
        this.setState({films: filmTitle});
        this.setState({director: director});
        this.setState({date: dateFormat});
       // console.log(filmTitle);

      });

   }



    render(){

          return (
      <div>
              <h3 className="filmInfo"> Movie Title: {this.state.films} <div className="info"> director: {this.state.director} </div> release date: {this.state.date} </h3>
      </div>
           );


    }

            }




class FilmDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      error: null,

    };
  }






  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`${this.props.subreddit}`)
      .then(res => {
       // console.log(res);
       // var data = res.data.films;
        const posts = res.data.films.map(obj => obj);
        this.setState({ posts: posts });
       // console.log(this.state);
      //  console.log(posts[0]);
      })
    .catch(err => {
        // Something went wrong. Save the error in state and re-render.
        this.setState({
          error: err
        });
      });

   }


  renderError() {
    return (
      <div className="error">
        Something went wrong: {this.state.error.message}
      </div>
    );
  }


  render() {

     if(this.state.error){
       return this.renderError();
     }


    return (

      <div>

          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <Films key={post.id} name={post} />
                              )}
       </div> 
    );
  }

}



ReactDOM.render(<div>
  <Person />   </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I expect to just click on next character and data gets replaced
    The data will not rerender when i click on new character unless i clcik clear button. I tried ComponentWillUpdate on FilmDemo class also forceUpdate, do not know what else to try.

Comment: What is "the data"? Where is the `render` method of `FilmDemo`? Why do you `setState` twice in two consecutive lines (it renders twice)? `else if` would be cheaper than `if` `if` `if`. And in the end I think your problem would be solved with a few more `console.log` and a bit of patience.

Comment: I have added the rest of the code and the render method for FilmDemo.  I have tried many console.logs and different ways to make component rerender, like I mentioned I am a beginner to Rect so I probably am not using best practice for everything, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the placement of the `axios.get` call in the `FilmDemo` component. You're fetching data from your API in `componentDidMount`, which only fires once (after the component has been mounted). Since the component is mounted when you click on the first character, you never fetch data for any subsequent clicks, so the data don't change after the first click.

To fix this, you'll need to move the `axios.get` call somewhere that will get called on subsequent clicks. You have a couple options here, like componentWillReceiveProps or extracting the call to the parent.

I'd recommend extracting the API call to the parent as follows. Note that the code doesn't have any loading indicators, so you have to remember to wait a second for the API calls to complete and the newest information to become available.

```js
class Person extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.test = "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/";
    this.state = {
      characters: [
        {
          name: "Luke Skywalker",
          url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
        },
        {
          name: "Darth Vader",
          url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/4/"
        },
        {
          name: "Obi-wan Kenobi",
          url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/"
        },
        {
          name: "R2-D2",
          url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/"
        }
      ],

      url: "",
      person: "",

      // Pulled posts and errors into parent instead of storing
      // them in FilmDemo
      posts: [],
      error: null
    };
  }

  handleClick(cName, person, e) {
    this.setState({ person: person });
    this.setState({ url: cName });
    this.props.test = cName;

    // On each click, call the API and then call this.setState
    // this.setState triggers a re-render which garauntees
    // the newest information will show up
    axios
      .get(`${cName}`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.films.map(obj => obj);
        this.setState({ posts: posts, error: null });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
          error: err
        });
      });
  }

  _renderSubComp(link) {
    // Now, pass the fetched posts and possible errors down as props
    var url = <FilmDemo posts={this.state.posts} error={this.state.error} />;

    if (link === "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/") {
      return url;
    }

    if (link === "https://swapi.co/api/people/4/") {
      return url;
    }

    if (link === "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/") {
      return url;
    }

    if (link === "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/") {
      return url;
    }
  }

  render() {
    var people = this.state.characters.map(function(p) {
      return <p>{p.name}</p>;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <p
          className="clearButton"
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "null", "")}
        >
          <button>Clear</button>
        </p>
        <div className="people">
          <p
            className="peopleName"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(
              this,
              this.state.characters[0].url,
              people[0]
            )}
          >
            {people[0]}{" "}
          </p>
          <p
            className="peopleName"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(
              this,
              this.state.characters[1].url,
              people[1]
            )}
          >
            {people[1]}{" "}
          </p>
          <p
            className="peopleName"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(
              this,
              this.state.characters[2].url,
              people[2]
            )}
          >
            {people[2]}
          </p>
          <p
            className="peopleName"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(
              this,
              this.state.characters[3].url,
              people[3]
            )}
          >
            {people[3]}
          </p>
        </div>

        <span className="info-films example">
          <h3>{this.state.person}</h3>
          {this._renderSubComp(this.state.url)}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Films extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      films: [],
      director: [],
      date: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`${this.props.name}`).then(res => {
      var filmTitle = res.data.title;
      var director = res.data.director;
      var date = new Date(res.data.release_date);
      var dateFormat = date.toDateString();

      // Each call to setState triggers a (potentially expensive)
      // re-render, so make sure to group these as follows:
      this.setState({ films: filmTitle, director: director, date: dateFormat });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 className="filmInfo">
          {" "}
          Movie Title: {this.state.films}{" "}
          <div className="info"> director: {this.state.director} </div> release
          date: {this.state.date}{" "}
        </h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class FilmDemo extends React.Component {
  renderError() {
    return (
      <div className="error">
        Something went wrong: {this.props.error.message}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    // Now, the appropriate information is passed down as props on each new click
    if (this.props.error) {
      return this.renderError();
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.posts.map(post => <Films key={post.id} name={post} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Person />{" "}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I left some comments to explain the things I changed.

There are also some other issues you might be concerned with going forward. For example, the `_renderSubComp` does not return a value in all code paths.

Happy coding!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, remember to mark it as accepted or upvote it. Good luck!